# How to say "To tend to"

Tags: traducción, verbos

How do I say "**to tend to**" as in:

- **I tend to** rant a little bit when I'm tired.
- **She tends to** forget what she came into the room for.

etc.

Maybe I should just use 'a veces', 'siempre', etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La traducción literal con "**tender a**" se entiende perfectamente:

> Tiendo a quejarme cuando estoy cansado.
>
> Ella tienda a olvidar para qué entró en la habitación.

Pero en estos ejemplos "**soler**" es mejor atendiendo a los pequeños matices del significado de "tender".

Una tendencia aplicada a las personas generalmente implica cierta voluntad o inclinación a hacer algo (tendencia a comer, a llorar, a meterse en problemas, tendencia política, etc.) pero olvidar no es un acto voluntario, es algo que te ocurre sin más. Y normalmente tampoco querrías dar la impresión de que te quejas por gusto, sino que el algo que te ocurre involuntariamente porque estás cansado. Así, quedaría mejor:

> Suelo quejarme cuando estoy cansado.
>
> Ella suele olvidar para qué entró en la habitación.

Pero si nos fijamos en los significados de soler:

- Dicho de un hecho o de una cosa: Ser frecuente.
- Dicho de un ser vivo: Tener costumbre.

Si "soler" se interpreta por "frecuente" (o "a veces") el mensaje será justo lo que posiblemente queríamos decir:

> Con frecuencia me quejo cuando estoy cansado.
>
> Con frecuencia ella  olvida para qué entró en la habitación.

Pero  si se interpreta por por "tener costumbre de " o "acostumbrar a", aunque correcto, vuelve a ser menos apropiado:

> Acostumbro a quejarme cuando estoy cansado.
>
> Ella acostumbra a olvidar para qué entró en la habitación.

Porque así no ponemos énfasis en el hecho (olvidar, quejarte a causa de) sino en la propensión (tendencia) del sujeto  *a hacer* eso, lo que sugiere cierta voluntariedad. Aunque en cierto contexto, por ejemplo de crítica o censura, puede que "acostumbra" sea justo lo queremos decir.

Comment: This is a very thorough response, I would definately go with `soler` for this one.

Comment: Uau! Una respuesta perfecta =) Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to say "to tend to" do something is with the verb [soler](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=soler). It would work with both of the examples you give. I'd also add that "a veces" and "siempre" have a slightly different meaning than "soler," just as "sometimes" and "always" have a slightly different meaning than "tend to."